# Android - java lang NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

can u please help me find whats wrong with this code, it gives me NullPointerException error

Here is the code

```
if (newF.isDirectory()) {
                    System.out.println("newF.isDirectory()" + newF.isDirectory());
                    Logo = new File(newF,"client_logo.png");
                    if (Logo.isFile()) {
                        System.out.println("Logo.isFile()" + Logo.isFile());
                        // fos = new FileOutputStream(Logo);
                        Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory
                                .decodeFile("/sdcard/Track Monitor/"
                                        + MonitoringController.routname
                                        + "/" + "client_logo.png");
                        // bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80, fos);
                        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bit);
                        setImage(d);
                    } else {
                        Thread.sleep(1500);
                        GetLogoFromSever();
                    }
                }
```

Here is the logcat:

> 06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.starware.track_monitor/com.starware.track_monitor.view.C_ControlsScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1491)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:676)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:348)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:141)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:456)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at com.starware.track_monitor.view.C_ControlsScreen$1.run(C_ControlsScreen.java:139)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:3717)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at com.starware.track_monitor.view.C_ControlsScreen.onCreate(C_ControlsScreen.java:132)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>   06-24 16:49:16.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10651):    ... 18 more

Comment: where is the stacktrace ?

Comment: please post the complete logcat output

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(10651): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.starware.track_monitor/com.starware.track_monitor.view.C_ControlsScreen}: post this code

Comment: @Zhuinden no need to post the whole code.. it works fine when i remove this code i posted above.. so the prblem in these codes above i posted

Comment: I see, then indicate line com.starware.track_monitor.view.C_ControlsScreen.onCreate(C_ControlsScreen.java:132)

Comment: the line is:
@Override

Answer (score 0):

The problem here I see is possibly, that You have a whitespace in your pathname:

```
     ("/sdcard/Track Monitor/" + MonitoringController.routname+ "/" + "client_logo.png");
```

The part "/sdcard/Track Monitor/" is maybe the error. You should handle such problems and replace whitespaces in path like:

```
      String filePath = "/sdcard/Track Monitor/" + MonitoringController.routname+ "/" + "client_logo.png";

      String filePathWithoutBlank = filePath.replace(" ","\\ ");
```

If this is not the Problem, come back and show us the logcat ouptut to give an exact answer.

### EDIT

You have to declare Your Activity inside the manifest.xml like this:

```
       <activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"  >            
</activity>
```

Comment: still same problem.. i added the logcat

Comment: It gives me error that my activity have not declared in the manifest.xml